# ¿Como inserto un visor de codigo en mi pagina?

Tags: html

Quiero poner este tipo de visor de código en mi página web ¿Como puedo lograrlo?.

[image: visor de código]

Comment: que tipo de página, usas wordpress o que tipo de blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para integrar código javascript, html, php, css, etc... hay muchas librerías js, yo te recomendaría http://prismjs.com/

Espero que sea lo que buscas.

Comment: Muchas gracias =), ya lo logré, muchas gracias =)

Answer (score 4):

Desconozco cómo generan el código en esa página concreta pero ese "visor" no es más que código html y css como este:

```css
pre {
    background: #262720;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: Consolas,sans-serif;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: .95em;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
pre .kw1, pre .me1 {
    color: #00d6ff;
}
pre .sy0 {
    color: #f92772;
}
pre .br0 {
    color: #aaa;
}
pre .st0 {
    color: #fff8ab;
}
```

```html
<pre>  <span class="kw1">var</span> app <span class="sy0">=</span> angular.<span class="me1">module</span><span class="br0">(</span><span class="st0">'formApp'</span><span class="sy0">,</span> <span class="br0">[</span><span class="br0">]</span><span class="br0">)</span><span class="sy0">;</span>
&nbsp;
  app.<span class="me1">controller</span><span class="br0">(</span><span class="st0">'MainCtrl'</span><span class="sy0">,</span> <span class="kw1">function</span> <span class="br0">(</span>$scope<span class="br0">)</span> <span class="br0">{</span>
    $scope.<span class="me1">formData</span> <span class="sy0">=</span> <span class="br0">{</span><span class="br0">}</span><span class="sy0">;</span>
  <span class="br0">}</span><span class="br0">)</span><span class="sy0">;</span>
&nbsp;</pre>
```

Comment: Gracias muchas gracias todos me ayudaron

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/), un plugin diseñado para reconocer código fuente y darle formato apropiado.

```js
$(function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

```css
.snippet .hljs {
  background-color: #262720;
  color: #fff;
}
.snippet .hljs .hljs-keyword {
  color: #00d6ff;
}
.snippet .hljs .hljs-string {
  color: #fff8ab
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.4.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.4.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<pre class="snippet">
<code class="javascript">
  var app = angular.module('formApp', []);
  
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.formData = {};
  });
</code>
</pre>
```

Esto no es exactamente lo que pones en tu ejemplo ya que highlight.js lo que reconoce es javascript que es el lenguaje como tal pero puede ser personalizado fácilmente a tu gusto.

Chequea la [guía de estilos](http://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/style-guide.html) y la [guía del lenguaje](http://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language-guide.html).